# PJAX with tawk.to

Tags: javascript, pjax, tawk.to

I'm using tawk.to on my site equipped with PJAX and it seems not working well. Tawk.to can't track visitors' current pages. I tried to put `<script>` on the top of `#container` which will be refreshed but not effective.

I tried `<script> window.paceOptions = { ajax: { trackWebSockets: false, trackMethods: ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT', 'PATCH'], ignoreURLs: [.*tawk.*] } } </script>` only to get an err.